# Insert into history table - oracle SQL - PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table X and and table Y. Table Y is history table. Whenever a record is inserted or updated or deleted in table X it will get inserted in history table Y. Now I am trying to update the history table with the missing records. For this I wrote a minus query to get the differences. I have to insert all these records into history table. I tried to use 'merge' and other forms of insert statements but not able to get exact output.

EX:

Table X

```
  A         B          C
EMP NO  EMP NAME    EMP ADD
```

Table Y

```
A          B           C      D        E        F
EMP NO  EMP NAME    EMP ADD st dt   end dt  indicator
```

While inserting I have to use three additional columns as values which have dates and indicator as table X does not have these columns. Please help me out to write an insert for this history table when there is a difference.

Comment: Show us your stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to do this.  One is to use `not exists`:

```
insert into tabley (Y, A, B, C, EMPNO, EMPNAME, EMPADD)
select X, A, B, C, EMPNO, EMPNAME, EMPADD
from tablex x
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from tabley
    where tabley.y = x.X
    )
```

Just make sure you define the same number of columns for the insert as you do for the select.  Depending on where the other fields come from, you may be able to supply them as well -- depends on your sample data and expected results.

Btw, this assumes the `x` values in `tablex` are your unique identifiers.  If not, you'll need to update the `where` criteria above.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create the data for the missing columns in table x (formatted for improved readability):

```
insert into tabley(empno
                 , empname
                 , empadd
                 , st_dt
                 , end_dt
                 , indicator)
select empno
     , empname
     , empadd
     , to_date(some_date_you_create)
     , to_date(another_date_or null)
     , (whatever_starting_indicator_value_is_allowed)
  from tablex x
 where not exists (select 1
                     from tabley y
                    where x.empno = y.empno);
```

Essentially, you have to create the missing values with some arbitrary thing you decide on.  This also assumes that empno is a distinct key value.